# Handling of arrays in VBA macros for Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I'm trying to write a simulator in VB (Excel macro) where the input to a simulation is taken from cells in one sheet. The input will be placed in a number of arrays, for example timePerUser(10) and bytesPerUser(10). Then there will be some simple if/for/while stuff to make calculations based on the arrays and finally I will write the results back to Excel. SO, Excel will only be used to provide input data and to display the results, everything else is happening inside of the macro, including changing values in the arrays.

I am used working with Matlab but can't use it for this simulator, so here are my questions:

1. Are there any existing matrix/array operations I could use within an Excel macro? For example, is there some command to check the smallest or the next smallest value in an array? The Excel function "SMALL" would be perfect, but it doesn't seem to work in macros. Or do I simply need to solve this with for-loops?
2. Are there any other suggestions on how to create the arrays? Is it better to have one big matrix where each row corresponds to time, data, user etc (an NxM matrix) or is it better to have separate arrays for each parameter?
3. How to speed up matrix/array operations? Any general suggestions?

Thanks!
Oscar

Comment: Can someone clarify why this question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel does have some simple array operations - SUMPRODUCT (Matlab equivalent: A*B'), MIN, MAX, ... Most of these, including SMALL, need to be called using `Application.WorksheetFunction.xxx` ; for example, the function SMALL can be called in VBA with the following:

```
nthSmallest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(r, n)
```

where r is an array or range, and n is an integer between 1 and `r.Cells.Count`

I would strongly urge you to use one variable per conceptual variable, rather than trying to be clever with multiple entities in one 2D array. Speedwise I suspect the difference is small; but the opportunity to write unreadable code is significant.

As for speeding things up: it really helps to define your variables (and especially your arrays) as some fixed type (rather than Variant), e.g.:

```
Dim a(1 To 10) as Double
Dim ii as Integer
```

and it may help a little bit to have all of the arrays use the same (default) base. Since I'm a Matlab junkie myself, I often work with array indices starting at 1 - you enforce this in VBA by adding

```
Option Base 1
```

at the start of your module. At this point, if you declare

```
Dim a(10) as Double
```

it is equivalent to

```
Dim a(1 To 10) as Double
```

Is also good practice for someone who is not proficient in VBA, to add

```
Option Explicit
```

at the start of the module, as it will ensure that any variables you did not declare (or more often, that you misspelled) will generate an interpreter error.

One other thing about arrays: as a Matlab person you are used to Matlab increasing array sizes as needed. In VBA it is possible to change array size dynamically at runtime, using, for example

```
ReDim Preserve a(1 To 20)
```

which will make the array `a` 20 elements in size. If it was shorter, it will be padded with zeros; if it was longer, it will be trimmed. This CAN be useful, but is QUITE expensive, since often the entire array needs to be copied to a new location. When you don't know in advance how large your array will be, it's better to overestimate (and check bounds) than to ReDim every time it needs to get bigger - and do a final `ReDim` at the end to get it to the right size.

Hope this is enough to get your started!

Comment: Good answer, +1. I'd contend that the 1d/2d array question is relatively preferential. For OP: Note that VBA supports declaration of arrays of multiple dimensions (I'm not sure what the limit is). Also, depending on the computational intensity of the work, it's *possible* (untested by myself!) that a multi-dimension array will be quicker than multiple "vectors". You may like to test this with your code if performance is important, because there are a number of very detailed considerations (you may be familiar with cache coherence, etc.) that might affect the result.

Comment: @mkingston - thanks for your inputs. I just ran some benchmarks; filling a 1000x1000 variant array took 125 ms, while the same with Double or Integer took 78 ms. There was no significant difference between that and a 1000000 element linear array (within the resolution and repeatability of the measurement).

Comment: Ugh, I feel like a bit of an idiot. It's not cache coherence that's a concern; it's cache misses caused by caching algorithms. Your test quite likely won't test for that. These Wiki pages have some relevant stuff on them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm. This problem is only likely to bother you if run-time is actually fairly long, otherwise you probably won't notice it. I only mentioned it in case OP *really* needed performance. I wouldn't bother unless you're actually having performance issues though.

Comment: Of course if OP *really* needs performance VBA isn't that great a constraint to have.

Comment: Yes - for real performance you would consider compiling a dll and calling it from VBA if needed (or maybe use a language like C to create an Add-In).

Comment: Thanks a 1 000 000! Great answer! I might be back with more questions later when I'm stuck again ;)

Comment: @rasco - you should "accept" the answer if you like it - there's a check box near the vote count...